# Service not found in NativeScript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am new to Angular nativescript, I created a service using the "ng generate service" command in my native angular application, but when importing the service I get the error that the module cannot be found

[image]

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "@nativescript/angular";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptHttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
/*
Pass your application module to the bootstrapModule function located in main.ts to start your app
*/
export class AppModule { }
```

ApiBackRequestService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiBackRequestService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient) {
    }

}
```

Login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiBackRequestService } from 'src/app/services/api-back-request.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ns-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    pokemon = [];

    constructor(private api: ApiBackRequestService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a code-sharing project? in the Login.component.ts file just add **@** before the src.

change

```
import { ApiBackRequestService } from 'src/app/services/api-back-request.service';
```

to

```
import { ApiBackRequestService } from '@src/app/services/api-back-request.service';
```

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem

```
import { ApiBackRequestService } from '../../services/api-back-request.service';
```